# Why does Chef keeps ovewriting my server files?

Tags: chef-infra

Chef keeps overwriting files on my server. For the life of me I can't find the setting to turn it off. Is there some sort of setting to disable auto heal of a server?

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution would be to stop chef-client daemon on your server (Usually runs every 30 mins). Then you should check the code of your recipes.